# What's the best way to group together several shapes?

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

What is the best way to group together a number of shapes on a canvas? I am making a game map, and I want to be able to move the rectangle shape (the map background) and have the shapes on the map move with the background? Thanks, please be very specific, i'm a noob

Answer (score 4):

Replace the rectangle with a nested `Canvas` and put all of the "child" shapes in that canvas.

Comment: i tried doing that, but is it possible get the absolute position of the child shapes relative to the main canvas?

Comment: @user1233846: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.translatepoint.aspx